# Turning column data to rows for each month in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have a daily rainfall data from the year 19810101:20181231 in a column. The data has two columns one for year and one for rainfall. I wanted to turn the daily rainfall data into rows. i.e. the years and the 12 months in a column and the daily rain values in rows according to the days of the month (28/29 for February to 31). I tried if else statement, and couldn't succeed. Please any help.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library (zoo)

dat <- read.csv('RF.csv')
dat$Date <- as.Date(as.factor(dat$Date), format='%Y%m%d')
x <- split(dat$RF, cumsum(strftime(dat$Date, '%Y%m'))) 
Newdata <- cbind(day = 1:31, setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(x, `length<-`, 31)), '%m'))
```

I expected, the years and the 12 months in a column and the daily rain values in rows according to the days of the month (28/29 for February to 31). I also tried if else statement also, but couldn't succeed. Please any help.

```
           1  2  3.... .................28/29/30/31 days
1981 1    RF
1981 2
.
.
.
1981 12
.
.
.
2018 12
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this `tidyverse` solution fit your needs?

```
# Generate sample data
startDate <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2001-06-30")
dateSeq <- seq(from=startDate, to=endDate, by="day")

# Format as data frame
df <- data.frame(date=strftime(dateSeq, "%Y%m%d"), rf=as.numeric(strftime(dateSeq, "%d")) * as.numeric(strftime(dateSeq, "%m")))

> head(df)
> date rf
> 1 20000101  1
> 2 20000102  2
> 3 20000103  3
> 4 20000104  4
> 5 20000105  5
> 6 20000106  6

# Reshape from long format to wide format
df %>%
  mutate(year=strftime(as.POSIXct(strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')), "%Y"),
         month=strftime(as.POSIXct(strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')), "%m"),
         day=strftime(as.POSIXct(strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')), "%d")
         ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=day, values_from=rf, names_prefix='day') %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  reframe(across(starts_with("day"), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names="{.col}"))

> # A tibble: 18 × 33
> year  month day01 day02 day03 day04 day05 day06 day07 day08 day09 day10 day11 day12 day13 day14 day15 day16 day17 day18 day19 day20 day21 day22 day23 day24 day25 day26 day27
> 1 2000  01      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
> 2 2000  02      2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20    22    24    26    28    30    32    34    36    38    40    42    44    46    48    50    52    54
> 3 2000  03      3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30    33    36    39    42    45    48    51    54    57    60    63    66    69    72    75    78    81
```

Comment: Note that the code above assumes that you only ever have one rainfall value for each unique date.